# I want to know a definitive lineage of all the prophets for whom the details are available

Tags: prophets, prophet-ibrahim, prophet-lut

From Prophet Adam (pbuh) to Prophet Muhammadh sallallahu alaihi wa sallam, can anyone provide the lineage of all the prophets, whichever is available with you.

I heard recently in a speech, that Prophet Lut (pbuh) is a nephew of Prophet Ibrahim (pbuh), and they lived during the same period, and Angels came down with a good news of a son for Prophet Ibrahim (pbuh), and at the same time announced the punishment for the people of Prophet Lut (pbuh). I am not sure of this relation. Please also correct me if it is actually Prophet Ibrahim (pbuh) to whom the angels were sent during the period of Prophet Lut(pbuh).

Is it possible to get the details of who is nephew of whom and who is son of whom of the prophets, and all the relations among them?